# Hide class conditionally

Tags: javascript, equality

I am new to jQuery and I have been struggling with a following task:

I have two dropdown menus in SharePoint 2013. I want the `Environment` field to disappear when `WFE` value is selected in the `Role` menu.

I am not able to validate whether the `WFE` was picked or not:

```
$().ready(function () {
    $('.Role').change(function () {
        if ($('.Role').val() = 'WFE') {
            $('.Environment').hide();   
            alert('Changed!');
        }
    });
});
```

and

```
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" bgcolor="black" >
    <tr >
        <td>
          <!--Environment is a drop down menu in SharePoint 2013---->
            <b>Environment</b><br>
            <span class="Fields Environment" data-displayName="Environment"></span>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr >
        <td>
         <!--Role is a drop down menu in SharePoint 2013---->
            <b>Role</b><br>
            <span class="Fields Role" data-displayName="Role"></span>
        </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I have read quite a few threads and not a clue. Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.Role').val() = 'WFE'
```

should be

```
$('.Role').val() === 'WFE'
```

`=` means assignment, `===` means strict type and value equality which is almost always what you want! `==` can be used but can bite you because it does silent implicit conversions that can introduce subtle errors that are very hard to find. Explicit is always better than implicit.

[JavaScript Comparison Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

> JavaScript has both strict and type–converting comparisons. A strict
>   comparison (e.g., ===) is only true if the operands are of the same
>   type. The more commonly used abstract comparison (e.g. ==) converts
>   the operands to the same Type before making the comparison. For
>   relational abstract comparisons (e.g., <=), the operands are first
>   converted to primitives, then to the same type, before comparison.
>
> Strings are compared based on standard lexicographical ordering, using
>   Unicode values.

Answer (score 0):

Your `=` is issue

correct answer is :

```
if ($('.Role').val() == 'WFE'){}
```

= Assigns  value

== Compares values

**Update:More explanation**

If you assign value using `=` and use `if` around the expression like `if(count = 1)` then count gets value as 1 and it evaluates to true no matter what.

But if you use comparison operator `==` `if(count == 1)` , then it will check if count is equal to value 1 . If it is if will be evaluate the expression to true, and the statements will be executed in it.

Comment: @JQuery.PHP.Magento.com We should not care such thinks in SO. As there are tons of people around the globe...

Comment: @Bhojendra Well, a downvote without an explanation/comment is a rude thing to do. Especially on a fresh post that isn't obviously wrong.

Comment: @JQuery.PHP.Magento.com, and we cannot stop such people having crazy for .... They are like spam!!!

Comment: @Tomalak , I added more explanation for people who love to downvote just because they dont understand `=` and `==`

Answer (score 0):

First change:

```
 $().ready(function () {
```

[because it is not recommended to use](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

To this:

```
$(documenet).ready(function(){
```

Second change:

```
if ($('.Role').val() = 'WFE') {
```

To this:

```
if ($('.Role').val() == 'WFE') {//use == or === to compare
```

---

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.Role').change(function () {
       if ($('.Role').val() == 'WFE') {
         $('.Environment').hide();   
         alert('Changed!');
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: `$().ready(function () {...}`  is the same as `$(documenet).ready(function(){...}` - why should the OP change the shorter form to the longer one?

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Sorry. (I was thinking of `$(function () {...}`)

Comment: Thank you for suggestions and help. However, it still does not compare the value... The script works if I remove the condition - class disappear, alert pops up. But does nothing when condition is there... Is there any other approach to copmare values more suitable?

Comment: without seeing a fiddle I couldn't say

Answer (score 0):

Works for me....

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.Role').change(function () {
       var Selected = $("select[title='Role']").val();
       if (Selected == "WFE"){
            $('.Environment').hide();   
            alert('Changed!');
         } 
     });
 });
 </script>
```

Thank you everyone!
Chahoo